# django-taggit - display existing tags on the django-admin add record page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-taggit

I have created a test vlog application using django/python and [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit).

The vlog and tags are working as they should.

However, I want to list all the existing tags in the django-admin interface for new and updated vlog entries - similar to displaying the tags as a filter on the django-admin list page.

This will make the selection of new or existing tags for each new or updating vlog entry that much easier.

Here is what I mean by adding the tags as `help-text` on the tags input field:

My models.py code:

```
class VlogDetails(models.Model):
    ....
    vlog_video_image_url = models.URLField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=250, unique=True, help_text='http://img.youtube.com/vi/You_Tube_URL/0.jpg')
    ....
    tags = TaggableManager(help_text='List all the available tags here.')
```

Here is the django-admin input form interface:

[image]

Is it possible to display the existing tags in another manner on the new / edit django-admin page?

I have already listed the existing / existing tags on the django-admin list page as a filter as shown below. This filter display does not display on the new / update input forms.

django-admin filter code:

```
class VlogDetailsAdmin(BaseDetailsAdmin):
....
    list_filter = [
        'vlog_date_published',
        'tags',
        'vlog_timestamp_added',
        'vlog_timestamp_updated'
    ]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have tried several things but none work and I cannot find any related ideas in the docs. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is to override the form initial values take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.get_initial_for_field

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

I don't think that adding the tags to the new vlog page is possible - that is not possible for my level of coding experience.

However, after more investigation, I stumbled to an obscure post about [django-taggit-autosuggest](https://bitbucket.org/fabian/django-taggit-autosuggest).

Follow the docs to install and set up the django-taggit-autosuggest.

Instead of listing all the existing tags in the help. The autosuggest option displays all the existing tags with the related letters, as shown below:

[image]

And again:

[image]

I hope that this helps someone.